# Annoying 1-pixel band between Border and Label?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to get rid of an annoying 1-pxel band of un-drawn background between a border and a label control.

Specifically, my XAML looks like this:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Viewbox Margin="0,0,5,3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
        <Border BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="#BF272727" Background="#BF272727">
            <Label Padding="-3" Content="Testing" Foreground="Red"/>
        </Border>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

And my output looks like this:

[image: label with 1 pixel between border and label background]

Notice that the border brush and the label background both have a semi-transparent color. I've fiddled with other properties of both the border and the label and haven't found anything that will cause this single pixel between the border and label to get filled with the background color. I imagine it is something simple, but I haven't stumbled on it yet. I've tried setting the Background property on the label instead of the border, but with no change in results.

Comment: Don't set BorderBrush at all, or set BorderThickness to zero. It seems redundant to set BorderBrush and Background to the same color.

Answer (score 1):

WPF's device-agnostic rendering works very well most of the time, but yes…occasionally you'll see artifacts like this, due to adjacent elements being anti-aliased, causing pixels that nominally should be exactly the same color having some variation.

In your case, you should omit the border thickness and brush altogether. To do that and still have the same visual appearance, you need to include padding, so that the border element is expanded out to the size it would have had, had there been a non-zero thickness border. And of course, without the border included, the corner radius needs to be adjusted up (by half the original border thickness).

The following produces the result you seem to want:

```xml
  <Border Background="#BF272727" CornerRadius="3" Padding="2">
    <Label Padding="-3" Content="Testing" Foreground="Red"/>
  </Border>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turn on aliased edges in either your Border control or any of its parents:

```
RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this disables anti-aliasing for the control and all its descendants. It removes the artifact that's caused by the anti-aliasing, of course, but it also **disables anti-aliasing**. The resulting degradation in visual quality may or may not be an acceptable trade-off, especially when there's an alternative that resolves the issue without any visual degradation.